# count столбца и вывод данных из этого столбца

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Извиняюсь за глупую формулировку вопроса я не знаю как по другому спросить.
Запрос ради примера.
`SELECT count(*), info FROM person_info WHERE  info_type_id =21`
Я хочу посчитать все значение из таблицы, и еще вывести столбец где применяю `where` как это сделать?

Comment: Как минимум два варианта -  условное агрегирование и оконные функции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COUNT делает группировку.
Если нужно общее количество строк и отдельный SELECT на выражение, то, на мой взгляд, лучше сделать два запроса.

Comment: А если запрос сложный `SELECT name, count(*),info
FROM name n
LEFT JOIN person_info pi ON n.id=pi.person_id
LEFT JOIN cast_info ci ON n.id = ci.person_id
LEFT JOIN title t ON ci.movie_id=t.id
WHERE role_id in(1,2) and t.kind_id=1 and person_role_id IS NOT NULL and info_type_id=21
GROUP BY name,pi.info
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
limit 10` где в добавок `where  info_type_id =21`  мне нужен  COUNT(info)